# String Parsing in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have below string output

```
VDIR "WorkFlowWebApp/Test/" (physicalPath:D:\New folder (2))
```

Which i need to parse and get the physical path associated with it.
In this case it is D:\New folder (2), so how can i get the physical path in a variable in batch script.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "string=VDIR "WorkFlowWebApp/Test/" (physicalPath:D:\New folder (2))"
rem get relevant part:
set "physp=%string:*physicalPath:=%"
rem remove last char:
set "physp=%physp:~0,-1%"
echo %physp%
```